# Change DateLastModified property of Folder to match file within

Tags: vbscript

I have a number of folders, each with files inside the folder.

The structure looks something like this:

```
Folder.No.1
Folder_No_2
Folder No 3
```

and the files within are something like:

```
Folder.No.1\My.Movie.1.mp4
Folder.No.1\My.Movie.1.txt

Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.mp4
Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.jpg
Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.txt

Folder No 3\My Movie 3.mp4
```

As you can see, some folders contain `.` in the name, some contain `_` and some contain spaces.

The one consistent factor is that each folder will *always* contain an .mp4 file, regardless of anything else.

Therefore, how can I change the `Date Modified` date/time of the folder to match that of the .avi file contained within the folder? Can I do this by copying the `DateLastModified` from the file inside (the child) to the parent folder using VBScript?

So far I am working on something like this:

```
Dim objShell, objFolder, objFile

    Set objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strDir)

    Set strDir = objFile.GetFolder("C:\Temp")

For Each objFile In objFolder
    If UCase(objFolder.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "MP4" Then

    objFolder.Items.Item(strDir).ModifyDate = DateLastModified
        WScript.Echo objFolder.Name
    End If       
Next
```

but it fails when calling from command line with: `cscript CopyDateToParent.vbs`

Can anyone please help to correct this to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try my code :

```
StrFolder="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" 'Your folder

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(StrFolder)
Set Folder = objShell.NameSpace(StrFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
Name=objFile.Name
strExtension = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(Name))
    If strExtension = "mp4" Then
     Set objFolderItem = Folder.ParseName(Name)
     objFolderItem.ModifyDate = DateLastModified 'Example : "01/01/2008 8:00:00 AM"
    End If
Next
```